# *Compiler specific* build and run giving error in output

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, codeblocks

When I'm running the following code on **Visual Studio 2013**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch;
    printf("Enter an alphabet: ");
    scanf_s("%c",&ch);
    switch(tolower(ch)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':       
            printf("Alphabet is a vowel\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Alphabet is a consonant\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

...it outputs with error as:

```
Enter an alphabet : a
Alphabet is a consonant
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This error is **same** for any alphabet choice in **switch**.
But the same code gives correct output in **CodeBlocks**:

```
Enter an alphabet : a
Alphabet is a vowel

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.824 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &ch);` --> `scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, could you please give me any clue - why this is needed in VS2013 ?

Comment: see [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `scanf`:

```
scanf (" %c", &ch);
```

And please, note the indention in here between

```
"
```

and

```
%c
```

as it may cause some errors if not indented.